# Complexity about charset, vi(vim), and secureCRT

Tags: c, character-encoding, vi, sys

Issues about charset are always puzzling to me when programming, especially when my programming environment differs from the production environment.
I use secureCRT as my terminal tool. I can adjust `Options → Session options → Appearance → Character encoding` to display the content properly only if this is coherent with the charset of the content. But when use vi to input/edit/create something in secureCRT, it gets complicated.

#### There are 3 variables:

1. the `$LANG` environment variable of my linux server
2. the `$LANG` environment variable of my working computer

   - windows and secureCRT are running on it
3. the secureCRT setting

   - `Options → Session options → Appearance → Character encoding`

If these 3 variables are not uniform, then any chinese characters that I type into vi(vim) will be displayed as a mess (i.e. A=UTF-8,B=GBK,C=GBK (GBK is for chinese)). This is quite complex. vi accepts the bytes from my IME (which is the google chinese IME) and these bytes are correct for a chinese character in GBK(variable B). However, secureCRT displays these bytes as characters according to GBK (variable C). My question is why does it display them incorrectly?

If I bypass vi(vim) but use the same set of A,B,C variables (i.e. if I create a GBK file in windows and upload it to my server) then vi(or more/less/cat) that file, all the characters show correctly. What is the difference between using vi to create some chinese content and using vi to only show a file's content? What happened when I used the IME to type into vi?

I think this problem would be quite useful for us to thoroughly understand charset/font. Many thanks for any light shed on this.

Comment: even the LANG variable for my linux server is utf8，but vi only accpet bytes from the IME,it won't convert these bytes according to utf8 charset,because vi(vim) does not know "the input bytes is in gbk stream,i will convert it to utf8"---it has no info about which charset my IME is using,it only accept bytes ,and secureCRT display them in the screen

Comment: Conner，THANKS for your typesetting。It is a pity that no body show interest about this topic

Comment: What does `:echo &encoding` show?